# Ionic: Preserve $scope when navigate to another view

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app using Ionic Framework (Angular+Cordova).

The app have a News section with a list of news loaded from a server in JSON, then I tap in a new to open the Single New's View, but when go back to the list of news, $scope has been cleared and must get again the news list from the server.

Is this the usual behavior or am I doing something wrong?

How could I prevent this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: you should create a `service` object that retrieves and saves this kind of object, you inject the service into your controller and request the data from that

Comment: Anyway there are another variables in the $scope used for change the UI and news filtering that i need to preserve and cant save that with the service

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why my $scope attributes keep reseting in my AngularJS application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939244/why-my-scope-attributes-keep-reseting-in-my-angularjs-application)

Comment: This is working as expected. Every time you instantiate a new controller (perhaps by going to a view with a controller on it), a new $scope variable is injected in. Controllers generally should not keep state between visits. I would recommend creating a service that gets the news from the server once, then returns that result until you need it refreshed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should save this kind of data in a separate service, something in the line of this:

```
app.service('NewsService', ['$http', function($http){
    var newsPromise;

    this.getNews = function(){
        if(!newsPromise){
            newsPromise = $http.get('news.json');
        }
        return newsPromise;
    };
}]);

app.controller('NewsController', ['$scope','NewsService', function($scope, NewsService){
    NewsService.getNews().then(function(data){
        $scope.news = data.data;
    })
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `$rootScope`. As Onosa mentioned in the comments, every time you instantiate a new controller a new `$scope` variable is injected in, but the `$rootScope` (as the name says) keeps preserved for the whole life of your app (it's global).