# Render directive in parent controller defined in child controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Basically i would like to achieve something along the lines of this:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController as parent">
    <render-page-controls></render-page-controls>

    <div ng-controller="SomeController as some">
        <page-controls>
            <page-control title="Something" url="{ '/something/' + some.id }" visible="some.someCondition"></page-control>
            <page-control title="Something else" url="{ '/something-else/' + some.thing.id }" visible="some.someOtherCondition"></page-control>
        </page-control>
    </div>
</div>
```

It comes down to defining a set of page controls with references to variables on the scope of the child controller and somehow rendering that one level up. Also these expressions need to be reevaluated when the contents of those variables change.

Is this possible at all and if so how would go about doing this?

Comment: Its unclear whats the problem. There is not relation between `render-page-controls` and `SomeController`

Comment: Try using a service to share your data across controllers/directives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568057/ionic-preserve-scope-when-navigate-to-another-view/25568192#25568192

Comment: @Satpal that's exactly the problem, access to the child scope and preserving the expressions so they can still be evaluated later when the user changes values on the page

Comment: @red-X at first i defined the page controls in `SomeController` using a PageControlsService, but i want to define them in the "view" and use the scope of the child controller

Comment: What about defining a property in the parent scope (example: $scope.childData = {}). And in your some controller use that property to store the data you want to share with the parent controller? Since some will be a child scope of parent they both have access to that property.