# search results on the previous page should not be refreshed when clicked on back button

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Am using Ui-router to navigate the pages in Angularjs,when I searched for some results in the first view and clicking on a link in that view it will navigate to the second view i.e., Details view.Now,when I click a href link which will take back to the first search page,it is getting refreshed and am not able to see the previous searched results.I have used history.go(-1) function in the dynamic HTML page but its not working.Can u help me out how can we persist the loaded search results in the previous view.

**This is my app.js**

// module to display provider details

```
angular.module('admApp', [ 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap' ]).

config([ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/providerSearch');
    $stateProvider
    .state('viewPrvdDtlPage', {
        url : '/viewPrvdDtlPage/:prvdId',
        templateUrl : 'viewPrvdDetail.html',
        controller : 'ViewPrvdDetailCtrl'
    }).state('providerSearch', {
        url : '/providerSearch',
        templateUrl : 'providerSearch.html',
        controller : 'ProviderSearchCtrl'
    });
    } ]);
```

**this is my services.js**

```
 angular.module('admApp').service("ViewPrvdDetService", [ '$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    this.fetchPrvdDetail = function(prvdId) {
        var defered = $q.defer();
        var httpPromise = $http.post('viewPrvdDtl.htm', prvdId).success(function(data) {
            var providerDetail = {};
            providerDetail = data;
            defered.resolve(providerDetail);
        });
        return defered.promise;
    };
} ]);

angular.module('admApp').service("ProviderSearchService", [ '$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    this.searchByCriteria = function(provider) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var httpPromise = $http.post('find.htm', provider);
        httpPromise.success(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
} ]);
```

**this is my controllers.js**

```
 angular.module('admApp').controller("ViewPrvdDetailCtrl", [ '$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', 'ViewPrvdDetService', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, ViewPrvdDetService) {
    ViewPrvdDetService.fetchPrvdDetail($stateParams.prvdId).then(function(data) {
        $scope.firstName = data.prvdFrstNm;
        $scope.lastName = data.prvdLstNm;
        $scope.taxIdentification = data.prvdTin;
        $scope.fax = data.tPrvdDmgrphs[0].prvdFaxNum;
        $scope.dbo = data.tPrvdDentistat[0].dntBirthDt;
        $scope.stCode = data.tPrvdDmgrphs[0].prvdAdrStCd;
        $scope.city = data.tPrvdDmgrphs[0].prvdAdrCityNm;
        $scope.zip = data.tPrvdDmgrphs[0].prvdAdrXpndZipCd;
        $scope.pdpStatus = data.tPrvdPpoNetwrks[0].pdpStatus;
        $scope.specialty = data.tPrvdDentistat[0].spclSchNm;
        // $scope.email = data.tPrvdDmgrphs[0].prvdEmailAdrTxt;
        $scope.phone = data.prvdKeyTelNum;
        $scope.npi = data.prvdNpiId;
        $scope.providerKey = data.prvdRecId;
        $scope.demograph = data.tPrvdDmgrphs;
        $scope.dentistat = data.tPrvdDentistat;
        $scope.ppoNet = data.tPrvdPpoNetwrks;

        // this is for the specialty shown at top links
        $scope.specialty = data.tPrvdDentistat[0].spclSchNm;
    });

    $scope.goBack = function() {
        window.history.back;
    };

} ]);

angular.module('admApp').controller(
        "ProviderSearchCtrl",
        [
                '$scope',
                '$http',
                '$timeout',
                'ProviderSearchService',
                function($scope, $http, $timeout, ProviderSearchService) {

                    $scope.pageFunc = function(data) {
                        $scope.list = data;
                        $scope.currentPage = 1; // current page
                        $scope.entryLimit = 10; // max no of items to display in a page
                        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; // Initially for no filter
                        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
                    };
                    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
                        if (pageNo <= ($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit)) {
                            $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
                        }
                    };
                    $scope.filter = function() {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
                        }, 10);
                    };
                    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
                        $scope.predicate = predicate;
                        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
                    };

                    $scope.searchValue = function() {

                        if ($scope.provider == undefined
                                || (!$scope.provider.providerTin && !$scope.provider.providerFullLastName && !$scope.provider.providerFirstName && !$scope.provider.prvdAdrCityNm
                                        && !$scope.provider.prvdAdrStCd && !$scope.provider.prvdTelNum)) {
                            $scope.searchCriteria = 'specifySearch';
                            $scope.filteredItems = -1;
                        } else {
                            $scope.searchCriteria = 'noRecords';
                            ProviderSearchService.searchByCriteria($scope.provider).then(function(data) {
                                $scope.pageFunc(data);
                            });
                        }

                    };
                    $scope.formatTin = function(event) {

                        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                            $scope.searchValue();
                        } else if ($scope.provider.providerTin != undefined) {

                            if (event.keyCode != 0 && event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 9 && (event.keyCode < 15 || event.keyCode > 21) && (event.keyCode < 33 || event.keyCode > 46)
                                    && (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && !(event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105)) {
                                alert("Please enter only numeric value for Provider TIN");

                                $scope.provider.providerTin = $scope.provider.providerTin.replace(/\D/g, '');

                            }
                        }
                    };
                    $scope.formatLast = function(event) {

                        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                            $scope.searchValue();
                        }

                    };
                    $scope.formatFirst = function(event) {

                        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                            $scope.searchValue();
                        }

                    };
                    $scope.formatCity = function(event) {

                        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                            $scope.searchValue();
                        }

                    };
                    $scope.formatPhone = function(event) {
                        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                            $scope.searchValue();
                        } else {
                            if (event.keyCode != 0 && event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 9 && (event.keyCode < 15 || event.keyCode > 21) && (event.keyCode < 33 || event.keyCode > 46)
                                    && (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && !(event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105)) {
                                alert("Please enter only numeric value for Phone Number");
                                $scope.provider.prvdTelNum = $scope.provider.prvdTelNum.replace(/\D/g, '');
                            }

                            if ($scope.provider.prvdTelNum.length >= 10) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                $scope.provider.prvdTelNum = $scope.provider.prvdTelNum.replace(/(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/, '($1) $2-$3');
                            }

                            if (event.keyCode == 8) {
                                $scope.provider.prvdTelNum = $scope.provider.prvdTelNum.replace(/\D/g, '');
                            }
                        }

                    };
                    $scope.formatState = function(event) {
                        // alert("provider tin is " + $scope.provider.providerTin);
                        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                            $scope.searchValue();
                        } else if (event.keyCode != 0 && event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 9 && (event.keyCode < 15 || event.keyCode > 21) && (event.keyCode < 33 || event.keyCode > 46)
                                && (event.keyCode < 65 || event.keyCode > 90)) {
                            alert("Please enter valid state code");
                            $scope.provider.prvdAdrStCd = $scope.provider.prvdAdrStCd.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, '');
                        }
                    };

                } ]);
```

**this is my index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- CSS (load bootstrap) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <style>
        .navbar { border-radius:0; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS (load angular, ui-router, and our custom js file) -->
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <title>Demo</title>

</head>

<!-- apply our angular app to our site -->
<body ng-app="admApp">

<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
<div id="topnav">
        <img src="img/logo.png" />
    <!--ul class="menuOptions">
        <li class="searchInput"><input id="search" type="search"></li>
        <li class="addSearch"><a href="#"><strong></strong></a></li>
        <li class="help"><a href="#"><span></span><label>Help</label></a></li>
        <li class="alert"><a href="#"><span></span><label>Alert</label></a></li>
    </ul-->
        <div class="loginName"><a href="#"><label>Sr.Clinical Reviewer</label><span class="userDropdown"></span></a></div>
    </div>

                <ul class="nav-bar">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Provider</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Claims</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Plan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="sub-nav-bar">
                    <li><a href="#">Directory</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Recommendations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="lastChild">WatchList</a></li>
                </ul>

    <div ui-view></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why my $scope attributes keep reseting in my AngularJS application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939244/why-my-scope-attributes-keep-reseting-in-my-angularjs-application)

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't work in that way.

'Back' in history is only a change in the route path: new template (search) and new controller. It has no information saved in 'memory'.

If you want 'remember' the user choise you have to write code (for example save it in cookies or store data in browser, etc etc).

---

Edit 9/3/14

---

In the controller **ProviderSearchCtrl** when you define the function **$scope.searchValue** you could store *somewhere* the **provider** data.

*somewhere* could be for example:

- [ngCookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)
- store info in $rootScope (note that $scoope, as suggested, exists only in the current control)
- an other service on backend for persistence of user preference
- html5 storage data (is like a sqlite on browser)
- ...

The choice is on your needs.

When you execute **ProviderSearchCtrl** you have to check if there is data stored or not. 
If you don't want to execute again the same search call in the server, you could save in $rootScope also the results and show them. I suggest this way only if you have to lighten the server loads.

Not tested, but an idea...

```
//...
$scope.searchValue = function() {

   if ($scope.provider == undefined
      || (!$scope.provider.providerTin && !$scope.provider.providerFullLastName && !$scope.provider.providerFirstName && !$scope.provider.prvdAdrCityNm
      && !$scope.provider.prvdAdrStCd && !$scope.provider.prvdTelNum)) {
          $scope.searchCriteria = 'specifySearch';
          $scope.filteredItems = -1;
     } else {

          // you have to define before $cookies.mySearchFormData
          if ($cookies.mySearchFormData.provider !== $scope.provider) {
              $cookies.mySearchFormData.provider = $scope.provider;
          }

          $scope.searchCriteria = 'noRecords';
          ProviderSearchService.searchByCriteria($scope.provider).then(function(data) {
          $scope.pageFunc(data);
     });
   }

};
//...
if ($cookies.mySearchFormData !== undefined && $cookies.mySearchFormData.provider !== undefined) {
    // First view load, re-execute the search
    $scope.provider = $cookies.mySearchFormData.provider;
    $scope.searchValue();
}
```

Regards

Comment: can you explain in detail

Comment: do a ride with $rootScope to take confidence with scoping pattern